# Power Shell Invoking an MSI

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, installation

I am trying to run an msi installer file using powershell. Below is my power shell code:-

```
$argumentlist = "/i D:\FolderTest\InstallerTest 1.9.0.39621 Setup.msi /qn /l*v D:\FolderTest\InstallLog.log"

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $argumentlist
```

Every time I try to run this code though The Windows installer appears telling me that the argumentList variable isnt set correctly. Can anybody tell me what the problem is with this code?

Answer (score 1):

I think that spaces in the msi filename are what's preventing the msiexec to work properly. Try something like:
`$argumentlist = "/i 'D:\FolderTest\InstallerTest 1.9.0.39621 Setup.msi' /qn /l*v D:\FolderTest\InstallLog.log"`

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell is a shell. It's designed to run commands you type. You don't need to use `Start-Process`. Just type the command and press `Enter`.

```
PS C:\> msiexec /i "D:\FolderTest\InstallerTest 1.9.0.39621 Setup.msi" /qn /l*v "D:\FolderTest\InstallLog.log"
```

As with any command, if a parameter contains spaces, enclose it in quotes.